# How to setup gitlab container registry inside docker?

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have got [gitlab](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) running inside the docker container on my localhost. I want to test gitlab container registry also in my localhost. But I don't know how to setup container registry inside docker container. I am using this instruction: http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/container_registry.html#container-registry-domain-configuration and I have tried to do steps from "Installations from source", but it doesn't created "Container Registry" option in repo settings in gitlab ui. So there is one option: "Omnibus GitLab installations", but there is requirement to use https.